# Single command to find files, zip and move to different location, delete the original files

Tags: linux, shell, ksh

I need to find files older than 45 days, zip them and move them to an archive folder and delete the original files.

```
find . -name '*.dat' -exec zip '{}.zip' '{}' ';' -exec mv '{}' ~/archive/ \;
```

Above command seems to work, but the original files are still in folder.

Comment: Why don't you make a nice script?

Comment: I have a script to clean up files with different use case and most of them are one liners. So I though I will try to put everything in one line using find.

Comment: You can make a function within your script. Calling that function is also 1 line.

Comment: I have the command "find . -name "*.gz*" -print | barges -I mv {} ~/archive

The command is working fine but throws an error as below
mv: '/home/<id>/test.dat.gz' and '/home/<id>/test.dat.gz' are the same file

But the file is moving to archive correctly. 
What is the cause of this error.

Comment: When `<id>` is `archive`, I understand: `find` moves a file to `/archive/`, continues looking for files, and sees a file in `~/archive/`. Moving the file from archive to archive will cause the error.

Comment: _I have the command "find . -name ".gz" -print | barges -I mv {} ~/archive_ - there are unbalanced quotes; and what is that `barges` command?

Comment: sorry it was typo error. It is "xargs" and I took care of this error by adding ! -path option to exclude search inside archive folder.

Answer (score 0):

Adopting Ipor's idea here is much sample and strait `find`

```
find . -name '*.dat' -exec zip -m '~/archive/{}.zip' '{}' \;
```

Answer (score -1):

man zip

> ```
>    -m
>    --move
>           Move  the  specified  files into the zip archive; actually, this
>           deletes the target directories/files after making the  specified
>           zip  archive.  If a directory becomes empty after removal of the
>           files, the directory is also  removed.  No  deletions  are  done
>           until zip has created the archive without error.  This is useful
>           for conserving disk space, but is potentially dangerous so it is
>           recommended to use it in combination with -T to test the archive
>           before removing all input files.
> ```

Answer (score -1):

```
find . -mtime +45 -name '*.dat' \
    -exec zip '{}.zip' '{}' ';' \
    -exec mv '{}' ../. ';' \
    -exec rm '../{}' \;`
```

Above command is fine,
btw.. Why, then move to delete? This seems not to be content.

Comment: May be I confused with my description. When I tried to zip the files, it left original files as it is. All I need is to find files older than 45 days, zip them and move them to archive directory.

Comment: I have the command "find . -name "*.gz*" -print | barges -I mv {} ~/archive

The command is working fine but throws an error as below
mv: '/home/<id>/test.dat.gz' and '/home/<id>/test.dat.gz' are the same file

But the file is moving to archive correctly. 
What is the cause of this error.

Comment: Where was running path? Perhaps as `find` have found a `archive`

Comment: yeah there was another archive folder. So I added ! -path clause to take care of this